# CrmImpersonator and IFD

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm

I have an asp.net page which works fine for internal calls to the services, however when used on an externally facing site I just cannot get it to function at all.

The CRMImpersonator works ok when accessed internally but when using the IFD interface all I get is a message saying

```
'Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' doesn't exist.
Parameter name: Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: 'Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' doesn't exist.
Parameter name: Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.Crm2007.CookieAndSoapHeaderAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Crm.WebServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated my code is as below

```
public string orgname;
public string crmurl;
public string metaurl;
public bool offline;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region CRM URLs and Organization Name

    //Determine Offline State from Host Name
    if (Request.Url.Host.ToString() == "127.0.0.1")
    {
        #region offline
        offline = true;

        //Retrieve the Port and OrgName from the Registry
        //RegistryKey regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\MSCRMClient");
        //orgname = regkey.GetValue("ClientAuthOrganizationName").ToString();
        string portnumber = regkey.GetValue("CassiniPort").ToString();

        //Construct the URLs
        string baseurl = "http://localhost:" + portnumber + "/mscrmservices/2007/";
        crmurl = baseurl + "crmservice.asmx";
        metaurl = baseurl + "metadataservice.asmx";
        #endregion
    }
    else
    {
        offline = false;

        //Retrieve the URLs from the Registry
        //RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSCRM");
        //string ServerUrl = regkey.GetValue("ServerUrl").ToString();
        string ServerUrl = "http://192.168.1.152:5555/MSCRMServices";
        crmurl = ServerUrl + "/2007/crmservice.asmx";
        metaurl = ServerUrl + "/2007/metadataservice.asmx";
        Response.Write("ServerURL " + ServerUrl + "<br>");
        Response.Write("CRMURL:   " + crmurl + "<br>");
        Response.Write("MetaURL:  " + metaurl + "<br>");

        //Retrieve the Query String from the current URL
        if (Request.QueryString["orgname"] == null)
        {
            orgname = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            //Query String
            string orgquerystring = Request.QueryString["orgname"].ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orgquerystring))
            {
                orgname = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                orgname = orgquerystring;
            }

        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orgname))
        {
            //Windows Auth URL
            if (Request.Url.Segments[2].TrimEnd('/').ToLower() == "isv")
            {
                orgname = Request.Url.Segments[1].TrimEnd('/').ToLower();
            }

            //IFD URL
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orgname))
            {
                string url = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
                int start = url.IndexOf("://") + 3;
                orgname = url.Substring(start, url.IndexOf(".") - start);
            }
        }
        Response.Write(orgname + "<br>");
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the Microsoft.Crm.Webservices.dll to the gac resolved this issue.

Also needed to use the following sql to ensure that the user was being impersonated:

```
Execute as user =@username
Select * from FilteredActivityPointer;
revert
```